Android app sync error void org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions$Substitution.with(org.gradle.api.artifacts.component.ComponentSelector)
I've looked on Stackoverflow for a solution to this to no avail.
I'm updating an old app that I have after my old computer shows signs of "fatigue."
I installed AndroidStudio Ladybug on LinuxMint as a FlatPak application but I
get the following problems:
The sync window says:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
'void org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions$Substitution.with(org.gradle.api.artifacts.component.ComponentSelector)'

My build.gradle (app) is
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 34
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.paullee.ghostexcursions"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 31
    versionName "31.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}


compileOptions{
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.7.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

// Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"

// Annotation processor
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"
}

And my build.gradle (project) is
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
            tasks.withType(JavaCompile)
                    {
                        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
                    }
        }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

My gradle-wrapper.properties is
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

The following website
https://medium.com/@mkcode0323/resolving-the-gradle-error-failed-to-notify-dependency-resolution-listener-253d584c6ce0
suggests using gradle 7.5 rather than 8.5
I'm wary about reverting to old version but I tried it and so I changed the relevant line to
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip

But when I run this, I get
Your build is currently configured to use incompatible Java 21.0.3 and Gradle 7.5. Cannot sync the project.

We recommend upgrading to Gradle version 8.9.

The minimum compatible Gradle version is 8.5.

The maximum compatible Gradle JVM version is 18.

However, I'm specifying the compileoptions (as above) to be JavaVersion.VERSION_11 so I don't know why it is saying "Java 21.0.3"
If I do java --version I find
openjdk 11.0.24 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.24+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu324.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.24+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu324.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

I can't find anywhere in the source files that specify Java 21*
I also get:
Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script '/tmp/ijMapper1.gradle' (/home/paul/.gradle/caches/7.5/scripts/b25n52h7zv8v111bro00um1z5).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

Which I assume is an error because I attempted to revert from gradle 8.5 to 7.5
Can anyone help please? I'm at a loss here. Many thanks, I appreciate your help.
